# (Oracle SQL) How to display info about customers that made orders in two years?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by

I have a table named Orders where There are information about customers and their orders made and I want to retrieve information only customers made orders both 2009 as 2010. How Can I get it? I've code the following statement but I don't retrieve any information.

```
SELECT   customer_id
FROM     cs_ordenes
WHERE    order_date BETWEEN '01/01/2009' AND '31/12/2009'
AND      order_date BETWEEN '01/01/2010' AND '31/12/2010'
ORDER BY customer_id DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to check if there is at least one order in each year.

```
select customer_id
from cs_ordenes
where order_date >= date '2009-01-01'
    and order_date < date '2011-01-01'
group by customer_id
having count(distinct to_char(order_date, 'YYYY')) = 2
```

`count(distinct to_char(order_date, 'YYYY'))` finds number distinct year from order date for each customer. In our case and since we have already filter the data for date range of two year using the WHERE clause, if the count is 2, then it means there was at least one order in each year.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gurv. I didn't know about it!!! I will search more information about aggregation in Oracle SQL. Thanks for your help. Your answer is CORRECT!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about simplifying the `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM cs_ordenes
WHERE order_date >= DATE '2009-01-01' AND
      order_date < DATE '2011-01-01'
ORDER BY customer_id DESC;
```

Your original logic would work if you changed the `AND` to `OR` between the two statements.  It is impossible for a single date to be in 2009 and 2011, so your query returns no rows.  The above logic is simpler, though.

Also, `BETWEEN` is dangerous to use with dates, simply because sometimes they have time components.  That is why I prefer the simple inequalities.

Comment: Yes, This statement retrieve information but I just want display information about customers that made orders in 2009 AND 2010!

Comment: Thanks for your consideration about use of BETWEEN with dates!

Answer (score 0):

The same `order_date` can be both in 2009 and 2010, so no rows are returned. One approach could be to count the distinct number of years each customer's orders have:

```
SELECT   customer_id
FROM     cs_ordenes
WHERE    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) IN (2009, 2010)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date)) = 2
ORDER BY customer_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

"
Select customer_id from orders
Where order_ date between 
To_date('01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy) and to_date('01-01-2010','dd-mm-yyyy')